# Go Back to Default Tumblr Layout

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

So after gratuitous theme installations and customizations my tumblr site just isn't looking how I want it to.  I've decided to just do the theme myself, but now I have one on there with all this extra stuff.

How can I go back to default layout so I have a clean slate to work on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to http://www.tumblr.com/customize (you can get there by clicking the cog wheel in the backend and then **Customize your blog**). Click *Themes* in the upper left, then search and click on *Optica*, which is the default theme. Click on **Use** to take the theme.